# Unattend install: "REG ADD" doesn't work

Tags: windows, registry

I'm trying to execute this commands in OOBE pass on Windows 7 unattend install:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>Administrator</Username>
                <Password>
                    <Value>UABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAA==</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
            </AutoLogon>
            <Display>
                <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
                <DPI>96</DPI>
                <HorizontalResolution>1280</HorizontalResolution>
                <VerticalResolution>800</VerticalResolution>
            </Display>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <NetworkLocation>Other</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            <TimeZone>Russian Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>QQBkAG0AaQBuAGkAcwB0AHIAYQB0AG8AcgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>UABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAA==</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <DisplayName>Admin</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>Admin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <LogonCommands>
                <AsynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <CommandLine>reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v prog /t REG_SZ /d c:\Myprogram\prog.exe /f</CommandLine>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                </AsynchronousCommand>
                <AsynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>4</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Network\NwCategoryWizard" /v Show /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000 /f</CommandLine>
                </AsynchronousCommand>
                <AsynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Network\NwCategoryWizard" /v Suppress /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f</CommandLine>
                </AsynchronousCommand>
                <AsynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Teamviewer /t REG_SZ /d C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe /f</CommandLine>
                </AsynchronousCommand>
            </LogonCommands>
        </component>
```

And registry not changed after install completed. Why?

(I also tried to run .cmd file with similar commands and import .reg file, but it doesn't worked.)

Comment: Try FirstLogonCommands instead.  It might be a good idea to run a command script with a pause at the end so that if there are errors you can see what they are.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried FirstLogonCommands. Stop the "script" to see errors - a good idea. But it's silent execution of commands, unfortunately.

Comment: When using FirstLogonCommands, you need to set RequiresUserInput to true in order to see the script run.  Include `cmd /k echo Hello` in the script to get an interactive console for troubleshooting.